# How to implement matrix gesture detector in flutter for multiple widgets, just like moving two- three text widgets on a image

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I'm trying to move different text widgets and scaling/ moving/ rotating them individually but not able to implement that as when I try to change one, the other widget also changes, and when I use matrix gesture detectors individually, they don't move on the entire screen.
Please help!
Thanks

Link to matrix gesture detector package I'm using https://github.com/pskink/matrix_gesture_detector

Comment: flutter introduced in built widget called *interactiveViewer*    https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zrn7V3bMJvg ,  try using this

Comment: Can't get desired thing as I wanted to move the widgets also with resizing.

Answer (score -1):

Just past this to your class 2 image can move rotate and scale even in same time
I hope it can help you

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1_185VhZ02h_QXLc4efWl3_kU2X2SFsF88oO2-vNblyI/edit?usp=sharing